# Configuring a 'retry delay' in MQ Series

Tags: ejb-3.0, jms, ibm-mq, jboss-mdb

I'm hoping someone can help me - I'm using JBoss 5.1 and MQ Series 7 in an EJB / JMS based application.  I have several message driven beans in my application, each listening on an MQ Series message queue.  When an error is encountered during the processing of a message, I need to be able to configure a 'retry delay', so that mq series waits some period of time before attempting to redeliver the message.  I have combed through MQ Series documentation extensively, and have not yet found a way to accomplish this in MQ Series.  I know that the JBoss default JMS provider has a way to do this, but I am currently limited to using MQ Series.  Since I haven't been able to set a retry delay - when I have a message that fails, my application gets stuck in a tight loop of delivering the message and rolling back continuously.  Can anyone help me understand if there is some config option in MQ Series that will allow me to wait X milliseconds before redelivering a failed message?

Answer (score 7):

This is likely to be an opportunity to craft a little infrastructure for such an issue.

Since you can look at the JMSDeliveryCount when the message has entered the bean (before you process it -- consider commit scope) and you can see that it has had a couple of rollbacks already, send the message around to a staging queue but attach the destination queue name in the jms properties so you can use it later.

A simple process can run on some interval to clear the **staging queue** (every 5 minutes for example) and send the message on to a **routing queue**.

Another process can sit on the **routing queue** and look at the jms properties (which added the destination queue name to) and send the message along to the orginal destination.

It's a poor man's broker but it will acheive the goal.  It is true that there is not much built in to really do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're out of luck. As far as I know the only parameters you can tweak in this scenario is the max number of times the message will be retried (BOTHRESH) and the name of the exception/backout queue (BOQUEUE) where the message will be sent if the number of retry attempts exceeds the max.

Paal

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a retry limit so that the continuous rollback will stop after a specified attempts.