# How to recover from deadlocks in Message Driven Beans in GlassFish?

Tags: glassfish, deadlock, message-driven-bean

I am running into a deadlock situation when receiving messages on a pool of MDBs in GlassFish. If I receive multiple messages that concurrently try to update the same set of rows, the MDB throws a LockAcquisitionException. Unfortunately the GlassFish JMS provider redelivers the message immediately causing the same exception to occur again. I was hoping to configure the JMS provider to redeliver after some delay, but this does not seem to be supported. Any ideas on how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at 
[Configuring a 'retry delay' in MQ Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322878/configuring-a-retry-delay-in-mq-series)

What about catching the error, sleeping, and then re-throwing it?

Comment: Unfortunately GlassFish does not offer retry delay. Sleeping is an option, but the J2EE spec frowns upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to some Oracle documentation on the configuration options: 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1794/aeooq/index.html

endpointExceptionRedeliveryAttempts

This will allow you to catch errors.  You could then implement an MBean on the Fault/RME endpoint and add in artificial delays

But there doesn't appear to be a way to put a retry delay in GlassFish at this time.

Comment: Agree. At this point I am thinking of abandoning GlassFish's native provider (OpenMQ) and going to HornetQ or ActiveMQ - both these provide more sophisticated ways of handling such scenarios (retry delays, message groups etc.). Unfortunately the road to integrating with other JMS providers is a tough one - the documentation is either dated or not very good. Failed miserably with ActiveMQ, but still trying!

Comment: Perhaps moving to FUSE (ActiveMQ with CXF and ServiceMix) http://www.fusesource.com would be useful??  -Disclaimer, I work for Progress, which owns Fuse Source.  http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhavanishankar/archive/2007/01/servicemix_on_g_1.html (servicemix w/glassfish)   Or you could just add the retry timeout logic to OpenMQ, being Open Source and all.  :-)  Best of luck!

Comment: Sounds interesting. Will take a look.