# add redeliveryPolicy to Websphere MQ message

Tags: java, spring, websphere, ibm-mq

I have a Websphere MQ and a java app receiveng messages from it. I want to make redelivering system if any exceptions is thrown .

Is there a way to add redeliveryDelay in my configuration spring xml?

here's my spring configuration:

```
<!-- JMS CONNECTION FACTORY -->
<bean id="MQFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="transportType">
        <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT" />
    </property>
    <property name="queueManager" value="${queueManager}" />
    <property name="hostName" value="${hostName}" />
    <property name="port" value="${port}" />
    <property name="channel" value="${channel}" />
</bean>


<bean id="JmsConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="MQFactory" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${username}" />
</bean>


<!-- JMS LISTENER -->
<bean id="Listener" class="jms.impl.Listener"></bean>

<!-- JMS CONTAINER -->
<bean id="JmsContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="JmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="${destination}" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="Listener" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jms.consumers}" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />

</bean>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306645/apache-camel-re-consume-jms-message-after-x-minutes-after-transaction-rollbac

Comment: @JoshMc i dont use apache camel

Comment: All of those suggestions are not camel specific.